# Difference between generic function whose return type is protocol and nongeneric function whose argument and return type are protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

When I work on the opaque types, I read this section in the official documents of Swift.

> Another problem with this approach is that the shape transformations
> don’t nest. The result of flipping a triangle is a value of type
> Shape, and the protoFlip(*:) function takes an argument of some type
> that conforms to the Shape protocol. However, a value of a protocol
> type doesn’t conform to that protocol; the value returned by
> protoFlip(*:) doesn’t conform to Shape. This means code like
> protoFlip(protoFlip(smallTriange)) that applies multiple
> transformations is invalid because the flipped shape isn’t a valid
> argument to protoFlip(_:).

This part made me consider about nested functions whose return type is protocol and I wanted to play about the protocol return types in the playground. As a result, I created a protocol called Example and also, a non generic and generic concrete types that conform to Example protocol. I kept "sample" method implementations which is protocol requirement as simple as possible because of focusing return types.

```
protocol Example {
    func sample(text: String) -> String
}

struct ExampleStruct: Example {
    func sample(text: String) -> String {
        return text
    }
}

struct ExampleGenericStruct<T: Example>: Example {
    var t: T
    func sample(text: String) -> String {
        return t.sample(text: "\n")
    }
}
```

After that, I created a generic function which has an argument constraint by Example protocol and returns Example protocol. Then, I tested my function as nested.

```
func genericTestExample<T: Example>(example: T) -> Example {
    return ExampleGenericStruct(t: example)
}

genericTestExample(example: genericTestExample(example: ExampleStruct()))
```

I got this error:

> Value of protocol type 'Example' cannot conform to 'Example'; only
> struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

This is what I expected. Function returns the protocol itself, not the concrete type that conforms it.

Finally, I wrote an another function.

```
func testExample(example: Example) -> Example {
    if example is ExampleStruct {
        return example
    }
    return ExampleGenericStruct(t: ExampleStruct())
}
```

When I run the code, I could nest this function successfully.

```
testExample(example: testExample(example: ExampleStruct()))
```

I can pass any value to both genericTestExample and testExample functions as long as it conforms to Example protocol. Also, they have the same protocol return type. I don't know why I could nest testExample function while I could not nest genericTestExample function or vise versa.

Comment: `testExample` accepts a parameter of type `Example`, which is also its return value - that's why it works here. `genericTestExample`, on the other hand, accept a parameter of type `T: Example`, but returns `Example` - which, as you noted, is not accepted because `Example` doesn't conform to `Example` - a requirement of `T`

Answer (score 0):

### swift 5.4
2021-09-27 08:36 UTC

@ceylanburak

you should use the **Opaque Types** in swift.

```swift
// some Example is **Opaque Types** !!!
func genericTestExample<T: Example>(example: T) -> some Example {
    return ExampleGenericStruct(t: example)
}
```

now follow your previous mind

```swift
genericTestExample(example: genericTestExample(example: ExampleStruct()))
```

and it equals to

```swift
let e1: some Example = genericTestExample(example: ExampleStruct())
genericTestExample(example: e1)
```